# Why are the urls and headers of two requests seemingly the same but have different status codes (404 and 200, respectively)?

Tags: python, http, scrapy

I am trying to crawl pages like this http://cmispub.cicpa.org.cn/cicpa2_web/07/0000010F849E5F5C9F672D8232D275F4.shtml. Each of these pages contains certain information about an individual person.

There are two ways to get to these pages.

One is to coin their urls, which is what I used in my scrapy code. I had my scrapy post request bodies like `ascGuid=&isStock=00&method=indexQuery&offName=&pageNum=&pageSize=&perCode=110001670258&perName=&queryType=2`to http://cmispub.cicpa.org.cn/cicpa2_web/public/query0/2/00.shtml.

These posts would return response where I can use xpath and regex to find strings like`'0000010F849E5F5C9F672D8232D275F4'` to coin the urls I really wanted:

```py
   next_url_part1 = 'http://cmispub.cicpa.org.cn/cicpa2_web/07/'
   next_url_part2 = some xptah and regex...
   next_url_part3 = '.shtml'
   next_url_list.append([''.join([next_url_part1, i, next_url_part3]))
```

Finally, scrapy sent GET requests to these coined links and downloaded and crawled information I wanted.
Since the pages I wanted are information about different individuals, I can change the `perCode=` part in those POST request bodies to coin corresponding urls of different persons.

But this way sometimes doesn't work out. I have sent GET requests to about 100,000 urls I coined and I got 5 404 responses. To figure out what's going on and get information I want, I firstly pasted these failed urls in a browser and not to my suprise I still got 404. So I tried the other way on these 404 urls.

The other way is to manually access these pages in a browser like a real person. Since the pages I wanted are information about different individuals, I can write their personal codes on the down-left blank on this page http://cmispub.cicpa.org.cn/cicpa2_web/public/query0/2/00.shtml( only works properly under IE), and click the orange search button down-right(which I think is exactly like scrapy sending POST requests). And then a table will be on screen, by clicking the right-most blue words(which are the person's name), I can finally access these pages.

What confuses me is that after I practiced the 2nd way to those failed urls and got what I want, these previously 404 urls will return 200 when I retry them with the 1st way(To avoid influences of cookies I retry them with both scrapy shell and browser's inPrivate mode). I then compared the GET request headers of 200 and 404 responses, and they looks the same. I don't understand what's happening here. Could you please help me?

Here is the rest failed urls that I haven't tried the 2nd way so they still returns 404(if you get 200, maybe some other people have tried the url the 2nd way):

http://cmispub.cicpa.org.cn/cicpa2_web/07/7694866B620EB530144034FC5FE04783.shtml
and the personal code of this person is
`110001670258`

http://cmispub.cicpa.org.cn/cicpa2_web/07/C003D8B431A5D6D353D8E7E231843868.shtml
and the personal code of this person is
`110101301633`

http://cmispub.cicpa.org.cn/cicpa2_web/07/B8960E3C85AFCF79BF0823A9D8BCABCC.shtml
and the personal code of this person is `110101480523`

http://cmispub.cicpa.org.cn/cicpa2_web/07/8B51A9A73684ADF200A38A5D492A1FEA.shtml
and the personal code of this person is `110101500315`

Comment: Please show us your code. Make sure you only give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: try to include "Referer: http://cmispub.cicpa.org.cn" in your request header